Why does putting display: flex on * selector render the CSS on the page?


* {
  display: flex;
  color: blue;
}
<body></body>



If you run the above snippet, why does the CSS render as text?

Virtually any display value, not just flex, will do this.

* with no other qualifications targets every single element in the entire document, including the style tags. In this case, that includes the default style tags for Stack Snippets. Style tags normally have a value of display: none and changing that causes their contents to be displayed as text.
You can avoid the issue by using a more restrictive wildcard, for instance limiting it to elements within the body tag.


body * {
  display: flex;
  color: blue;
}
<body></body>




Why does targeting the style tag and modifying its display value cause the browser to render the CSS on the page?

@RyanPeschel Because the initial setting is display: none;

@j08691 Ah okay, thanks! That makes sense

You can see Chrome's default user agent stylesheet at https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/resources/html.css and around line 800 is base, basefont, datalist, head, link, meta, noembed, noframes, param, rp, script, style, template, title {   display: none; }
